# How to convert Entity ArrayList to DTO ArrayList

Tags: java

I am adding some entity element to ArrayList of Entity
I want to add the same entity element to ArrayList of DTO

```java
List<Batch> newBatches = new ArrayList<Batch>();
List<BatchDTO> newBatchDTO = new ArrayList<BatchDTO>();

newBatches.add(batch); //batch is of type Entity
```

I want `newBatchDTO.add(newBatches)`

Comment: Should look into something like ModelMapper to easily map between objects: http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: Yes I tried modelmapper it wont worked kindly help

Comment: does `Batch` and `BatchDTO` have any relation ship? can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is perhaps a in `List` like

```
addAll()
```

so

```
newBatchDTO.addAll(newBatches);
```

could work.

Comment: Hi Ali  if i use addAll() it says The method addAll(Collection<? extends BatchDTO>) in the type List<BatchDTO> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Batch>)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList1.addAll(ArrayList2)
```

Or
During Creation of 2nd arraylist itsef:

```
ArrayList<E> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<E>(arrayList2);
```